# Mock window object in Jasmine unit test case

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a test case but I'm stuck as I'm not able to replicate the window in the unit test cases in jasmine .

I have a class as follows

```
 public init(): void {
    this.Icon['text'] = window['SWIPE']['src'];
    this.Icon['altTag'] = window['SWIPE']['alt'];
  }
```

I tried to mock the above window object   as follows in spec.ts file

```
 let window = {
      'SWIPE': { 'src': 'image', alt: 'image' }
    };
```

The init class is being caled from other class based on condition and it is as followed

```
 public onMessageReceived(event: object) {
        switch (event && event['event']) {
          case 'onNavigation':
            this.init();
            this.isReady = true; 
            break;
    }
    }
```

the test case for the same i have written as follows

```
it('should set isReady as true on onNavigation value in switch', async(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      component.onMessageReceived({ event: 'onNavigation', data: {} });
      expect(component.isReady).toBeTrue();
    });
  }));
```

and value of window i tried and mocked in beforeEach as below

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;


    let window = {
      'SWIPE': { 'src': 'image', alt: 'image' }
    };


    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

still when I run the test case i get an error as " **TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined**"  where would I be going wrong any guidance would be helpful as I'm still learning to write test cases in jasmine

Comment: `let window` declares a *local* variable named window, that's **not** going to be seen by anything referencing the *global* window. One simple solution is to have a *service* that wraps the global window, a facade the rest of your code can use, then inject a test double of that for testing.

Comment: Can you please provide an example for the same request you @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is to stub the `window` object for a test

```js
// backup / restore the property.
const backup = window.SWIPE;
beforeEach(() => backup = window.SWIPE);
afterEach(() => window.SWIPE = backup);

// now the test
beforeEach(() => {
  // no let of const
  window = {
    'SWIPE': { 'src': 'image', alt: 'image' }
  };

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

PS. The right way would be to refactor the application in order to provide `window` as a token. Then you might fake it via `providers`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **ChromeHeadless** - you need to mock browsers history state to override URL's query this way:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  const search = `name=value&name2=value2`;
  window.history.pushState({}, 'Test', `/dummy-link.com?${search}`);
});
```

I hope, that helps.